# IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream> not casting

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, covariance, iasyncoperation

I have this class **CustomFileStream**, below is its signature

```
public class CustomFileStream : IRandomAccessStream {}
```

But when I use it like this,

```
IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStream> IStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode accessMode)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new CustomFileStream()).AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

I get a compilation error,

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<CustomFileStream>' 
to 
'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream>'
```

Can someone please see if I am doing something wrong here.

THanks.

Comment: What's the point in using `StartNew` just for the sake of creating tasks? You can simply `Task.FromResult`. Btw your code doesn't work because `IAsyncOperation<T>` isn't covariant. There are numerous posts in stackoverflow explains this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible due to the fact that `IAsyncOperation<T>` isn't [`covariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

> Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter. This allows for implicit conversion of classes that implement variant interfaces and implicit conversion of delegate types.

A covaraint interface is declared with the `out` modifier added to it in the generic type declaration, so as `IEnumerable<out T>`.

To get around your problem, you can explicitly cast the returned instance back to an `IRandomAccessStream`:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (IRandomAccessStream)new CustomFileStream()).AsAsyncOperation();
```

As a side note - using `Task.Factory.StartNew` to imitate asynchoronous behavior is bad practice. [*You shouldn't expose async wrappers over sync method calls*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)